# Integrate Paypal checkout laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-5.3

I'm currently developing a little shop system. Now I want to integrate a simple PayPal checkout. Just want to press checkout, log in to PayPal (as a customer), click pay and that's it, I get the money and he gets a confirmation.

Now, for Laravel I found 2 plugins, both relying on [this](https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment). But somehow I don't come clear with those. Also, I found [this](http://jslim.net/blog/2014/09/19/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4/), but its too old and different now, using Laravel 5.3. I also found [this tutorial](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration), but it also doesn't seem to be what I need (at least I guess so). I already created two sandbox accounts, a personal and a business acount, and I also have a user key and secret key.... But now, how can I use them?
What's the easiest way to just implement a quick way to checkout, entering some product data, the complete price and just be able (as a customer) to log in and click okay? I don't want more basically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **netshell/paypal** for my current POS App. It's pretty good and not complex. Check their documentation from [here](https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal).

Comment: what I'm wondering there, the import (`use`) is Paypal, but they use PayPal, why?

Comment: It's just typo. Actually, you can use like use Paypal;

Comment: It's depend on how you aliases.

Comment: and it would work how I want? and where do I have to set the config? In the same controller as the `getCheckout` function?

Comment: You can follow step by step instruction from their documentation. getCheckout is just example. Configuration must go under app/config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 5.3 why not go with the new cool Cashier? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/billing

Comment: i didn't try it, what are the benefits?

Comment: i just need shopping cart and paypal checkout and maybe invoice generation

Comment: I haven't use it myself yet (stuck with the LTS) but since it's integrated in the main framework I assume that would be easier to integrate. Maybe I'm being too optimistic or being nonsensical since I cannot provide an example. Sorry if I'm being mysleading here :-/